# Why are the eigenvalues of $I_R + \beta' \alpha$ bounded by one?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

Trying to understand the Granger-Johansen Representation Thm (see p. 7 [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~sjo/papers/OverviewPreprint.pdf); we are assuming Condition 5).

We have $(p \times r)$ matrices $\alpha, \beta$. We know that $|eig(a \beta')| \leq 1$ and that $det(\alpha_\bot' \beta_\bot) \neq 0$, where $\alpha_\bot$ is an orthogonal complement of $\alpha$. It is claimed that this implies $|eig(I_R + \beta'\alpha)| \leq 1$. Why is this the case?

I know $eig_i(I_R + \beta'\alpha) = 1+ eig_i(\beta' \alpha)$, but can anyone see why $ eig_i(\beta' \alpha) \in [-2, 0]$?

EDIT: Actually, is $eig_i(I_R + \beta'\alpha) = 1+ eig_i(\beta' \alpha)$ only true for symmetric $\beta'\alpha$? In that case, I don't even have that.